# Delete all admin user except administrator

Tags: terminal, user-account

I would like to delete all the users who have admin privileges except for a user named "administrator"

> dscl . -delete /Groups/admin

I think the above command will delete all admin users, but is there a way to edit the command to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over all users in the admin group, deleting them one by one, leaving your chosen account alone as opposed to deleting the admin group itself.

Also, use care to not delete any built in accounts since that would break your os. Typically user accounts have ID greater than 500 so you’ll piece together a bit of scripting:

- https://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x

I’m not going to post a working script since you’ll want to carefully craft your deletion to be reversible and also clean up user home folders after you delete each user. Making an error on that script could cause substantial data loss.

Comment: Make a comprehensive backup BEFORE you run any script like that...

Comment: Yes indeed - backup and pre-downloaded OS reinstall / verified good Recovery HD or network that supports internet recovery boot would be my minimum starting point. I’d delete the users first and then delete the data later if I were starting on an automation project like the OP asked.